# output for System.out.print("Hello") in Android program

Tags: java, android

I want to see any variable (String var) value in my android program.
You can say for debugging purpose.

When I am printing anything using, say System.out.print("Hello") 
Then I am unable find this output any where.

Do anyone have idea where to find this output.

Here is my code-

```
package com.test1.nus;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        System.out.print("Hello");

        ....
     }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your output will be logged to `logcat`

Assuming you are using eclipse:

```
Window > Show View ---> Logcat (If this not visible, select other--Android--Logcat)
```

Comment: Hi Nambari,
I could not find my output string in my logcat.
Don I need change any setting?

Comment: No, I don't think you need to do any setting changes (except make sure no filters set in logcat window). If your code is being executed, you should see System.out statement.

Comment: Opening/Viewing the LogCat window truly worked for me. I seems to be a detour before sending output to /dev/null, because I'm seeing my System.out.println text in LogCat exactly when I expect it.Thanks!
(For anyone on Mac using Android Studio app, you can view LogCat by, in main Android Studio menu at the top, click View, then Tool Windows->Logcat. The logCat window should open in your lower app area where console and compile errors usually appear. But Logcat is one of the tabs at the bottom. Click the Logcat tab and you should see System.out output on the right-hand side of that window.)

Answer (score 5):

By default, the Android system redirects `stdout` (`System.out`) output to `/dev/null`, which means your messages are lost.

Instead, the common pattern to log debug strings in Android is the following

```
import android.util.Log;
```

Then at the top of your class `YourClass`

```
private static final String TAG = YourClass.class.getSimpleName();
```

And to log debug strings you need to call

```
Log.d(TAG, "your debug text here");
```

which in your case results in

```
package com.test1.nus;

import android.util.Log;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Log.d(TAG, "Hello");

        ....
    }
```

Finally you can see your debug strings in Eclipse via

`Windows > Show view > Other` and select `LogCat`

and if required filter by the tag of `YourClass`.

However, if you really need to see messages written by `System.out.println` you need to tell Android to route them to logcat via the following shell commands

```
$ adb shell stop
$ adb shell setprop log.redirect-stdio true
$ adb shell start
```

and then you will be able to see your debug messages in Eclipse via LogCat view and the tag `stdout`.

You can get more details from the official documentation here http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-log.html

Answer (score 2):

See this link: http://www.droidnova.com/debugging-in-android-using-eclipse,541.html
It will show some screen shots related to logcat.  There you can find out your output message.

Follow this: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check your output in the android emulator use `Toast messages`.

The result with system.out.println("....") will be displayed in `logcat`.

To check in android `emulator/device`.just do like this

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you take a look at the [android.util.log](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html) class. The Android developer pages has a [good introduction](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-log.html) for using it. (In fact, I just found this today since I'm learning Android programming myself.)

Answer (score 0):

If you use the AVD s that will give you a more interesting experience than just print in the log. [Here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html) they have described all those things perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You are better off using Logs if it is for debugging purposes.

There are various methods available like Log.v() Log.d() Log.i() Log.w() and Log.e() for verbose, debug, info, warn and error logs respectively.

Then you can check the logcat while debugging the application.

For further reference, go [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html).